# DS18B20 randomly dissapear from the devices list

Tags: pi-4, wiring, ds18b20

I have **4 DS18B20** sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi 4, with a resistor of **10kOhm**.

All of the sensors randomly disappears from the w1/devices.

In `config.txt` the `dtoverlay=w1-gpio` as well as the `gpiopin=4` is present.

The sensors are connected to **3.3V (physical pin 1)**, and **GPIO 4 (physical pin 7)**, **ground** is connected to the **physical pin 30**.
It was previously connected to 5V.

Maybe this will also help, if the devices goes missing if I take out the power pin and plug it back it will reappeare. The cables cannot be a problem, because after it appeared for the first time I resoldered everything with new resistor and new cables.

Any ideas why that can happen?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, You have what appears to be an easy fix. Replace the 10K resistor with something in the 3.3K range that should solve the problem. I have seen this many times. It worked better on the 5V because you had more current to drive the capacitance of the cables. Yes cables can be a problem, depends on how long they are and the capacitance they are presenting to the circuit. I believe changing the resistor should solve the problem. Also be cautious placing 5V on a GPIO pin can damage it and your Pi. I think in this case the 10K limited the current to a safe level. Let us know how you do.

Comment: Hey thank you for the response. I fogot to mention that previously I used a 5kOhm resistor when it as connected 5V (physical pin 2), The cables are just the normal jumper with a length of 10cm. Also this issue was not present untill I used a breadboard but since I had to switch to a terminal block this just randomly appeared. Tomorrow I'll try to solder on a smaller resistor, I'll let you know if it worked.